# JSONException trying to get value from JSON

Tags: java, json

I am trying to decode a json response in java with ant from my api but I get an error

The JSON is `[{"order": "test","tablenum": 1}]`

```
String url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/order/1";
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");

con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}

System.out.println(response);
String res = response.toString();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject newJSON = jsonObject.getJSONObject("order"); // error is here
System.out.println(newJSON.toString());
```

The error tells me Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["order"] not found.

Comment: Seeing the json itself would be helpful.

Comment: And please, next time make some extra effort to format your code before posting it.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Just new here,  sorry! A little Help wold be huge for me !

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that your JSON is actually an array. The brackets [] indicate an array of objects in your JSON. This means your JSON is an array with one object in it. This should help you solve the problem. You need to handle the JSON as an array of objects.